# SegmentedButton from Flutter changes its size when at least 1 button is selected

Tags: flutter

The `SegmentedButton` from Flutter shows a strange behavior when no button is selected. If you click on the leftmost or rightmost button, the width of the `SegmentedButton` changes.

What is this change in width all about?

My example is based on the Flutter code sample for [SegmentedButton](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/api/lib/material/segmented_button/segmented_button.0.dart).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const SegmentedButtonApp());
}

class SegmentedButtonApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SegmentedButtonApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const <Widget>[
              Spacer(),
              Text('Multiple choice'),
              MultipleChoice(),
              Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum Sizes { extraSmall, small, medium, large, extraLarge }

class MultipleChoice extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultipleChoice({super.key});

  @override
  State<MultipleChoice> createState() => _MultipleChoiceState();
}

class _MultipleChoiceState extends State<MultipleChoice> {
  Set<Sizes> selection = <Sizes>{};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SegmentedButton<Sizes>(
      segments: const <ButtonSegment<Sizes>>[
        ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.extraSmall, label: Text('XS (Click me)')),
        ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.small, label: Text('S')),
        ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.medium, label: Text('M')),
        ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.large, label: Text('L')),
        ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.extraLarge, label: Text('XL (Click me)')),
      ],
      selected: selection,
      onSelectionChanged: (Set<Sizes> newSelection) {
        setState(() {
          selection = newSelection;
        });
      },
      multiSelectionEnabled: true,
      emptySelectionAllowed: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Versions used

- Flutter: 3.10.2 (channel stable)
- Dart: 3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `SegmentedButton` expects every `ButtonSegment` to have an `icon` by default. You can get around this by simply adding `showSelectedIcon: false` to `SegmentedButton`.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this problem too recently, and I think it is because it's trying to adapt to the lack of the `icon` property of `ButtonSegment`. I tried keeping the icon there with `icon: Icon(null)` and it kinda worked, although it leaves an empty space to the left of the label.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SegmentedButton<Sizes>(
  segments: const <ButtonSegment<Sizes>>[
    ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.extraSmall, label: Text('XS'), icon: Icon(null)),
    ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.small, label: Text('S'), icon: Icon(null)),
    ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.medium, label: Text('M'), icon: Icon(null)),
    ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.large, label: Text('L'), icon: Icon(null)),
    ButtonSegment<Sizes>(value: Sizes.extraLarge, label: Text('XL'), icon: Icon(null)),
  ],
  selected: selection,
  onSelectionChanged: (Set<Sizes> newSelection) {
    setState(() {
      selection = newSelection;
    });
  },
  multiSelectionEnabled: true,
  emptySelectionAllowed: true,
 );
}
```